# How do I install this python package?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to learn django and I have completed the official django 1.7 "polls" app and also the popular gswd. Now I am trying to understand the codebase of everyblock.com They provide the backend code for learning purposes. This is the README file on everyblock

```
==========
everyblock
==========

This package contains code/templates that are specific to EveryBlock.com. They
are released to fulfill the terms of the grant that funded EveryBlock's
development and are likely not of general use.

Overview
========

The package is split into these directories:

    admin -- EveryBlock's internal admin application for managing its data
    cities -- City-specific data-acquisition scripts (for 15 U.S. cities)
    media -- CSS file for the admin
    states -- State-specific data-acquisition scripts
    staticmedia -- A Django template tag specific to EveryBlock.com media files
    templates -- Templates for the admin
    utils -- Various utilities used on EveryBlock.com

Quickstart
==========

0. Install PostgreSQL, PostGIS, Django, psycopg2.

1. Install the everyblock package by putting it on your Python path. Also
   install the ebdata, ebpub and ebgeo packages.

2. Start a Django project.

3. Put the smorgasbord of eb-specific settings in your settings file. It's
   probably easiest to just start with the file ebpub/settings.py and tweak
   that (or import from it in your own settings file). The application won't
   work until you set the following:

       DATABASE_USER
       DATABASE_NAME
       DATABASE_HOST
       DATABASE_PORT
       SHORT_NAME
       PASSWORD_CREATE_SALT
       PASSWORD_RESET_SALT
       METRO_LIST
       EB_MEDIA_ROOT
       EB_MEDIA_URL

   See the documentation/comments in ebpub/settings.py for info on what the
   various settings mean.

4. Run "django-admin.py syncdb" to create all of the database tables.

5. Run "django-admin.py runserver" and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ in your
   Web browser to see the site in action.
```

I have downloaded ebdata and ebpub packages and unzipped. I can see the files. I have installed PostgreSQL, PostGIS, Django, psycopg2. How do I go ahead with the next steps. I don't get how the three Packages can be installed by putting them in python path, start a django project and get it running locally. Any help?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Oops. Sorry I forgot to mention. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: are installation questions considered on-topic at stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you installed your dependencies, they may already be in your python path.

Run python from your terminal and see if you can import django. If you can it's already in your python path.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9
>>> import django
>>>
```

If that works, you can create a new django project

```
django-admin startproject everyblock
```

then just copy all the files you unzipped into the project folder and modify the settings.py file to point to your database.

(NB: Everyblock was released in 2009. It won't run using the latest version of Django without making some changes. It's also not a trivial project to begin with, so you may want to start with a different project until you are a little more comfortable.)

Comment: Thanks! That was pretty useful to me :) If you could also suggest some simple yet elegant open source django projects that I can install and browse across models, Views and Templates, that would be helpful :)

Comment: Checkout https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources - It's probably also worth mentioning `pip` and `virtualenv`. Virtualenv is particularly useful when you are learning, because you can install a bunch of stuff in an environment and just delete it when you are done. All those dependencies are completely removed, so you don't end up with a bunch of stuff installed on your computer